# How to make my ImageView responsive to onClickevents while .startAnimation() is running?

Tags: android, multithreading, animation

I'm new to android, and I'm facing a problem where I'm trying to make my `ImageView`, which is playing an animation through `startAnimation()`, to become Invisible as the user clicks on it. what happens however is that only after the animation is done the `Imageview` becomes invisible. my assumptions was it's because they both run on the UI thread. surprisingly however, when I changed my event handling from `setVisibility` to `startAnimation()` it actually listened to the click, interrupted the animation and restarted it!

To override my problem, which did turn out nice, I made a new `Animation` object that opposite to the first, which shows the `Imageview`, hides the `Imageview` and it worked perfectly, but I'm still curious as to why my `Imageview` was selectively responsive to different event handling?

This code change visibility only after the animation is done

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    face = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.face);
    final Animation showAnimation=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,R.anim.animation);
    face.startAnimation(showAnimation);
    face.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            face.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }
    });
}
```

this code changes the animation "while" the original is playing

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    face = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.face);
    final Animation showAnimation=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,R.anim.animation);
    face.startAnimation(showAnimation);
    face.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Animation hideAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,R.anim.animation1);
            face.startAnimation(hideAnimation);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: the SetVisibilty() worked when  I added clearAnimation()

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `face.setVisibility(...)`, instaed tt should be:

```
face.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }
});
```